# not sure, Is it connect mongo or not

Tags: php, mongodb

I have problem with my php code. I try to coonect mongodb in my server. But webpage doesn't show the right text and there's no error msg. so I get confuse that is it connect ??

here is my code. please take a look. I'm very glad with all help from

```
$username = "serveruser";
$password = "serverpass";

try
{
    echo "Class connectMongo<br>";
    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://$username:$password@192.168.7.8");
    $db = $m->selectDB('databasename');

    echo "pass connect<br>";

    $list = $db->listCollections();
    foreach ($list as $collection) 
    {
       echo "this is -> $collection... ";
    }
}
catch (MongoConnectionException $e) 
{ 
    die('Error connecting to MongoDB server'); 
} 
catch (MongoException $e) 
{ 
    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
}
```

and Here is what web show.

```
Class connectMongo
```

I try `var_dump($m)`, `var_dump($db)`, `var_dump($list)` but nothing happen.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Comment: got it. Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/connectMGDB/gettest.php on line 20
but my line 20 is $m = new Mongo("mongodb://$username:$password@192.168.7.8");

Comment: Is that mean it doesn't know Mongo ??

Comment: so lesson 1: If you've got a problem, find out if there is an error message. Add that error message to your question, error messages are very important in debugging things. Do you understand what that error message means?

Comment: It means that PHP has no class available called `Mongo`, yes. It does not "know" it. So you have got a fatal problem if you try to instantiate something that does not exists. It's like you want to drive a car, but there is no car. When you try to open the door and sit in there, you will fall onto your butt ;)

Comment: To get `Mongo` class you need to install it. Then you're fine. http://www.php.net/manual/mongo.installation.php

Comment: lol ok thank. I will try by myself :) thank you @Julian and hakre.

Comment: Can be as simple as enabling a .dll inside your php.ini or running some commandline as root in linux. Mongo is a common extension, installation should be documented, tested, mature, easy.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `$m = new Mongo('mongodb://$username:$password@192.168.7.8');` to this `$m = new Mongo("mongodb://$username:$password@192.168.7.8");`

You need double quotes to tell PHP it should parse the String and replace all variables with their values.

Also see http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: `var_dump` $list in order to check if there's something in there.

Comment: I try var_dump($m) , var_dump($db) , var_dump($list). But nothing happen. Web page didn't show anything except "Class connectMongo"